# Fill datagrid from module

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to fill a datagrid from a sub in a separate module. I must be missing something really simple but i can't seem to find what is wrong. No data shows up in my grid.

```
Public Sub FilldgvChargesPerContract(ByVal TelNr As String)
    'opvullen van de overzichtsgrid Charges Per Contract
    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    Dim oDR As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Nothing

    strSQL = " SELECT INVOICEPERIOD AS PERIOD, CATEGORY, SERVICE,AMOUNT FROM MOBILECOSTS_MOBISTAR_CHARGESPERCONTRACT WHERE PHONENR = '" & TelNr & "' AND DATEFROM > '1900-01-01' ORDER BY SERVICE DESC "

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectstring)
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "MOBILECOSTS_MOBISTAR_CHARGESPERCONTRACT")
    connection.Close()
    frmMobileCosts.dgvChargesPerContract.DataSource = ds
    frmMobileCosts.dgvChargesPerContract.DataMember = "MOBILECOSTS_MOBISTAR_CHARGESPERCONTRACT"
    frmMobileCosts.dgvChargesPerContract.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    'dgvOverviewNew.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "reset"
    frmMobileCosts.dgvChargesPerContract.TopLeftHeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

    'Laatste kolom uitbreiden voor het opvullen van de hele grid en alle andere cellen net groot genoeg voor inhoud
    frmMobileCosts.dgvChargesPerContract.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
    frmMobileCosts.dgvChargesPerContract.Columns("AMOUNT").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the following line...

```
frmMobileCosts.dgvChargesPerContract.DataBind()
```

Failing that, you may want to have the method in the module return the generated `DataSet` and then databind it to the DataGridView from within the function call on `frmMobileCosts` instead.